# Prepopulating Fields to jhipster form via URL Parameters

Tags: forms, jhipster

Hello Jhipster community
i would like to know if there is a way to populate form in jhipster through url parameter
for instance jhispter has generated for myentity a form callable by
http://localhost:8080/#/shipment(popup:shipment-new)

is there a way to prefilled it?

http://localhost:8080/#/myentity(popup:myentity-new)?name=new

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing looking at the url that you're using the Angular frontend.

You can retrieve that kind of data from via the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) service. Properties `params` and `queryParams` should provide you the data you're looking and let you populate your template.